# How to avoid program exception when ef model changes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I use a third party database with Entity Framework 6. This works fine; however, when a table within my model is changed (three columns were deleted), my program throws an exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name '<deleted column>'
```

I don't use any of these columns. I only read them from the database.
I can update my model, but then when there is another change in a table, my program will crash again. How can I modify my program so that it won't crash on the next database change?

Comment: Answer is You cant. Model is mapped to database, so if You delete columns from mapped tables it will crash. You can either update model or disable mapping on some columns but anyway it will always require Your work.

Comment: In other words: how can the EF know that the column that it cannot find contains data that is necessary for the program or data that is not used at all?

Comment: Maybe by specifying the table is read-only and specifying columns that dont need to be retrieved. Like in an sql statement you can specify which columns to retreive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Code First approach starting from database (generate classes from database). At the end of class generation you can delete entities that you don't need (i.e. entities related to all unused tables) or properties related to unused fields.
Disable migrations.
You can also delete intermediate files generated by EF code generation (files different from .cs files).
At this point, any changes to database that not affects mapped classes/properties does not cause errors in EF.

Comment: It only works for fields that have nulls allowed or a default value, otherwise I get: Error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line ...:Column <columnname> in table <table> must be mapped: It has no default value and is not nullable.

Comment: In that case the only way is that you keep that columns mapped knowing that if someone deletes them you will get an error. Are you accessing to the database only for read purpose? In this case you can also evaluate other mappers like Dapper.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a context with only the entities you need. Create entities with only the properties you need.
   see [EF code first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database).
2. Use [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database#7-fluent-api) to specify primary keys and more.

It will still crash though if any of your entities/properties gets changed/deleted